# If-Else-Statement in a Loop

Tags: excel, vba

My code is to concatenate and compare to a specific field. If it is equal then display it in a message box.

It is working in a single row but when I created a loop there is incorrect output.

```
Sub postURLGFormat(ByRef msgPostFormat As String)
    Dim URG, urgValue, urgCode, contentField, urlgField As String
    Dim numRows, i As Long

    numRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    contentField = Range("A1").Value
    urlgField = Range("J1").Value
    URG = "URG" & urgCode

    For i = 2 To numRows
        urgCode = Cells(i, "A").Value2

        If URG = urgValue Then
            msgPostFormat = msgPostFormat & Chr(149) & " " & urlgField & " " & URG & " is in proper format and with correct CT" & vbLf
        Else
            msgPostFormat = msgPostFormat & Chr(149) & " " & contentField & " " & urgCode & " is not aligned in " & urlgField & vbLf
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: A lot of issues here. First of all - your loop is testing for `URG = urgValue`. As of right now, those values are constant and the test is constant  at `URG = vbNullString` which will never be true. You need to reconsider your logic here or explain what you code is trying to do

Comment: @urderboy the code is About concatenate "URG" + Code field then Compare it to the group Field. 
A1 = J1
A2= J2
A3 = J3  ...

Comment: Note that `Dim numRows, i As Long` only declares `i As Long` but `numRows As Variant` you must specify a type for **every** variable `Dim numRows As Long, i As Long` otherwise VBA automatically assumes `Variant`. Same for your first `Dim` statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example loop to do what you need. You had a lot of variables that were not needed (unless you are using them later on that was not shown).

This method will loop through a range as determined by the last used row in `Column A`. Inside the `For Each` loop is the string comparison.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckVal()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim MyRange As Range, MyCell As Range

Set MyRange = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If "URG" & MyCell.Text = MyCell.Offset(, 9).Text Then
        'Do what you want here with CORRECT format
    Else
        'Do what you want here with INCORRECT format
    End If
Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score -5):

```
Sub postURLGFormat(ByRef msgPostFormat As String)

    Dim URG, urgValue, urgCode, contentField, urlgField As String
    Dim numRows, i As Long

    numRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    contentField = Range("A1").Value
    urlgField = Range("J1").Value
For i = 2 To numRows
        urgCode = Cells(i, "A").Value2
        URG = "URG" & urgCode
        If URG = urgValue Then
            msgPostFormat = msgPostFormat & Chr(149) & " " & urlgField & " " & URG & " is in proper format and with correct CT" & vbLf
        Else
            msgPostFormat = msgPostFormat & Chr(149) & " " & contentField & " " & urgCode & " is not aligned in " & urlgField & vbLf
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please dont just post code as an answer. Explain what you changed and how it fixes the problem.

Comment: This still won't work. Notice `urgValue` is never assigned a value/string. Right now the loop is always testing if `URG` is equal to a null string

Comment: @Loocid, the code is About concatenate "URG" + Code field then Compare it to the GROUP Field. 
A1 = J1
A2= J2
A3 = J3  ...

the output will be display using msgbox